# Server side for datatables in MVC not working on deployment

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, datatables

I am using server side processing for my datatables in MVC 2.0 . I have a controller which I am using to handle the incoming requests.
When I view the page on my localhost , it works fine and this is a sample of the request header it sends

```
http://localhost:42417/EmissionByRegion/DataProviderAction?_=1337611318226&sEcho=1&iColumns=40&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&.......[it goes on till 39 columns]
```

This gets a valid json response and everything works well.
But when I publish this code on a server which is using IIS 7.5 , when there is a postback to the server with the same request parameters:

```
http://domain.com/EmissionByRegion/DataProviderAction?_=1337612368137&sEcho=1&iColumns=40&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&........
```

I get a 404 - File or directory not found.

If i just type this : domain.com/EmissionByRegion/DataProviderAction

, it shows that the controller is there and is looking for valid parameters. So it is picking up the controller but when the parameters are being passed, it doesnt work.
Why is the same project not working on the server even though it was working on the local machine and what do I do to get it to work?
Please help .
Thanks

Comment: I think your url is too long !!!

Comment: See This: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Comment: Assuming you are using a browser to access the URL in question @Nildarar is likely correct. See [What is the maximum length of a URL?](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a POST request instead of a GET, there is really not much work that you need to do. [See this post.](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html)